# Failed to resolve transitive dependencies on JitPack release

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, jitpack

I'm working on building an android library and I want to include a dependency of the library as a transitive dependency into my app. Here's my library's `build.gradle` file:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.library'
    id 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'
}
group='com.github.rohg007.xxx'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles "consumer-rules.pro"

        ndk {
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    //SDK level dependencies
    implementation 'org.protoojs.droid:protoo-client:4.0.3'
    api 'org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.32006'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.1'
    implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.9.1")
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.6'

    implementation 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.7.1'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

It works fine and all transitive dependencies are resolved when I include the library as a module:

```
implementation project(path: ':huddle01-android-sdk')
```

But when I release on Jitpack and include it as a dependency:

```
implementation 'com.rohg007.xxx:0.1.0'
```

or

```
implementation ('com.rohg007.xxx:0.1.0'){transitive=true}
```

It fails to resolve the webrtc dependency.
How to include the transitive dependency on release as well?

Comment: Did you finad any resolution on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jitpack uses `./gradlew install` for generating the artifacts.

Adding an install block and manually appending the dependencies to the pom file worked for me.

Here's the `install` block that I added to the module level `build.gradle` file:

```
android {
    ...
}

dependencies {
    ...
}

install{
    repositories{
        mavenInstaller{
            pom.withXml {
                def dependenciesNode = asNode().appendNode('dependencies')
                configurations.implementation.allDependencies.each { dependency ->
                    if (dependency.name != 'unspecified') {
                        def dependencyNode = dependenciesNode.appendNode('dependency')
                        dependencyNode.appendNode('groupId', dependency.group)
                        dependencyNode.appendNode('artifactId', dependency.name)
                        dependencyNode.appendNode('version', dependency.version)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if it's a clean solution to the problem. If there are cleaner alternatives, do let me know.